# Class cannot be cast to Activity

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to finish my `SplashScreenActivity` with context from a non activity class `SessionManager`, but I keep getting this error:

```
com.package.Utils.AppController cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
```

I tried to finish the activity with this code I found online `((Activity)_context).finish()`

Here's my code

SessionManager.class

```
public class SessionManager {
 ...
 public void checkLogin() {

    if (!this.isLoggedIn()) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(_context, WelcomeActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        _context.startActivity(intent);
        ((Activity)_context).finish();
    } else {

        Intent intent = new Intent(_context, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        _context.startActivity(intent);
        ((Activity)_context).finish();
    }
}
}
```

AppController.class

```
public class AppController extends Application {

private static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();

private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
private ImageLoader mImageLoader;

private static AppController mInstance;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mInstance = this;
}

public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
    return mInstance;
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    }
    return mRequestQueue;
}

public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
    getRequestQueue();
    if (mImageLoader == null) {
        mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(this.mRequestQueue,
                new LruBitmapCache());
    }
    return this.mImageLoader;
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
    req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
    req.setTag(TAG);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
    if (mRequestQueue != null) {
        mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
    }
}
```

}

and in my manifest I have this

```
<application
           android:name=".Utils.AppController"
...
</application>
```

Comment: the _context is from AppController class instead of activity .. How are you saving the value for _context?

Comment: try using SessionManager(Activity activity) instead of context

Comment: Still doesn't work

Comment: Is it the same error ? You would need to change ((Activity)_context).finish(); to activity.finish();

Comment: I fixed it.. Thanks